# Need to map enum of bits like bit 0 indicates error 1, bit 1 indicates error2, with int binary sequence in C

Tags: c

Need to map enum of bits like (error is basically some string)
bit 0 indicates error 1,
bit 1 indicates error2,
bit 2 indicates error3,
.
.
.
.
bit n indicates error n

decimal value like int value= 283192 or any other value.

I tried by converting 283192 = 1000101001000111000.

Need help how to map this sequence with above enum using C.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, give a better explanation. Do you want to determine what errors are included in given int? Or you want to create enum with described features?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you are talking about, but that's a way to indicate which bits are set:

```
unsigned int bitmap = value;
unsigned int i = 1;
while (bitmap) {
    if (bitmap & 1) {
        printf("Error number %i\n", i);
    }
    bitmap >>= 1;
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
enum bad_errorcode {
  BADERR_NOBITS = 0,
  BADERR_BITONE = 1 << 0,
  BADERR_BITTWO = 1 << 1,
  BADERR_BITTHREE = 1 << 2,
  BADERR_BITFOUR = 1 << 3,
  /* ... */
};
```

Comment: Then you set errors with something like `error_code = SOME_ERROR | SECOND_ERROR_TOO` and test it with something like this: `if (error_code & SEVERE_ERROR) {printf("Help!!!")}`